# Convert a data frame according to formula (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, formula

I have a data frame `DF1`, for example:

```
DF1=data.frame(LA=1:5,VA=2:6)
```

I would like to estimate a model (not using a standard function), for which my formula is (for example) `~ LA + VA + I(LA*VA)`. Is there such a function in R that can convert my original data frame into a ready-made data frame according to my formula? For example:

```
magicFunction(DF1,"LA + VA + I(LA*VA)")
```

or

```
magicFunction(DF1,c("LA", "VA", "LA*VA"))
```

that would return:

```
    LA VA V3
 1:  1  2  2
 2:  2  3  6
 3:  3  4 12
 4:  4  5 20
 5:  5  6 30
```

My actual problem is that my formula is a lot more complicated than `~ LA + VA + I(LA*VA)` (and not actually confirmed at this stage), so I am looking for a function that can handle this.

(A solution with data.table would also work for me)

Comment: Try `transform(DF1, V3 = LA + LA + LA*VA)`

Comment: model.frame() does the work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
head(mtcars[c("cyl","gear")])
#                  cyl gear
#Mazda RX4           6    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       6    4
#Datsun 710          4    4
#Hornet 4 Drive      6    3
#Hornet Sportabout   8    3
#Valiant             6    3

head(model.frame(cyl~I(cyl*gear), data = mtcars))
#                  cyl I(cyl * gear)
#Mazda RX4           6            24
#Mazda RX4 Wag       6            24
#Datsun 710          4            16
#Hornet 4 Drive      6            18
#Hornet Sportabout   8            24
#Valiant             6            18
```

As @alistaire pointed out :

```
> model.frame(~LA+VA+cbind(V3 = I(LA*VA)), data = df)
#  LA VA V3
#1  1  2  2
#2  2  3  6
#3  3  4 12
#4  4  5 20
#5  5  6 30
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Comment: In this case, `model.frame(~LA + VA + cbind(V3 = LA*VA), DF1)`